# How to Make 'Stacked' Features in Featuretools using DFS

Tags: python, featuretools, feature-engineering

Reading the documentation, adjusting `max_depth` upward should result in complex 'stacked' features.

I'm finding I get no difference in features produced after adjusting `max_depth` to 2.

What am I doing wrong?

## `max_depth` = 1:  Original Features

```
feature_matrix, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                  target_entity='fish',
                                  max_depth=1)

features

>>>[<Feature: sex>,
 <Feature: length>,
 <Feature: diameter>,
 <Feature: height>,
 <Feature: whole_weight>,
 <Feature: shucked_weight>,
 <Feature: viscera_weight>,
 <Feature: shell_weight>]
```

## `max_depth` = 2:  Basic Primatives

```
feature_matrix, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                  target_entity='fish',
                                  max_depth=2)

features

>>>[<Feature: sex>,
 <Feature: length>,
 <Feature: diameter>,
 <Feature: height>,
 <Feature: whole_weight>,
 <Feature: shucked_weight>,
 <Feature: viscera_weight>,
 <Feature: shell_weight>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.COUNT(fish)>]
```

## `max_depth`= 3:  Same Features as max_depth = 2

```
feature_matrix, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                  target_entity='fish',
                                  max_depth=3)

features

>>>[<Feature: sex>,
 <Feature: length>,
 <Feature: diameter>,
 <Feature: height>,
 <Feature: whole_weight>,
 <Feature: shucked_weight>,
 <Feature: viscera_weight>,
 <Feature: shell_weight>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.shell_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.viscera_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.shucked_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.diameter)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.whole_weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.height)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.COUNT(fish)>]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Why does increasing the max_depth not increase the number of features created?**

One thing that stands out from the feature list is that every new feature created 
 is an aggregation-type primitive (Max, Mean, etc.).  There are no new features created using transformation-type primitives.

Without looking at the schema of the entity set I can only make a guess, but it appears that all the variables on the fish entity are either numeric (length, diameter, height, weight, etc.) or categorical (sex).  The `dfs` call that is made,

```
feature_matrix, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                  target_entity='fish',
                                  max_depth=2)
```

does not use the `trans_primitives` option, so DFS will use the default set of transform primitives when it tries to create new features.  The default set of transform primitives does not contain any primitives that can be applied to numeric or categorical variables, so no new transform features are being made.

I created a mock entity set to to try and replicate this scenario:

```
import featuretools as ft
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fish = pd.DataFrame({
    "sex": np.random.choice(['F', 'M'], size=10),
    "length": np.random.sample(size=10),
    "weight": np.random.sample(size=10)
})

es = ft.EntitySet("fish")
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="fish",
                         make_index=True,
                         index="id",
                         dataframe=fish)
es.normalize_entity(base_entity_id='fish',
                    new_entity_id='sex_adult',
                    index='sex')
```

I also only got new features created using aggregation primitives.

```
ft.dfs(entityset=es,
       target_entity='fish',
       max_depth=2,
       features_only=True)

>>>[<Feature: sex>,
 <Feature: length>,
 <Feature: weight>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.COUNT(fish)>]
```

Increasing the `max_depth` to 3 or more did not create more features.  However, once I used the `trans_primitives` option to add the `Percentile` transformation primitive (which can be applied to numeric type values), I got different results.

```
ft.dfs(entityset=es,
       target_entity='fish',
       max_depth=2,
       trans_primitives=[ft.primitives.Percentile],
       features_only=True)

>>>[<Feature: sex>,
 <Feature: length>,
 <Feature: weight>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(length)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.COUNT(fish)>]
```

Two new features, `Percentile(length)` and `Percentile(weight)`.  Increasing the `max_depth` to 3 added more features.

```
ft.dfs(entityset=es,
       target_entity='fish',
       max_depth=3,
       trans_primitives=[ft.primitives.Percentile],
       features_only=True)

>[<Feature: sex>,
 <Feature: length>,
 <Feature: weight>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(length)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.length)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.weight)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.COUNT(fish)>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.PERCENTILE(length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SUM(fish.PERCENTILE(weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.PERCENTILE(length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.STD(fish.PERCENTILE(weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.PERCENTILE(length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MAX(fish.PERCENTILE(weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.PERCENTILE(length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.SKEW(fish.PERCENTILE(weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.PERCENTILE(length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MIN(fish.PERCENTILE(weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.PERCENTILE(length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.MEAN(fish.PERCENTILE(weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(MAX(fish.length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(SUM(fish.length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(MAX(fish.weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(SKEW(fish.length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(MIN(fish.length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(MIN(fish.weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(MEAN(fish.weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(STD(fish.weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(COUNT(fish))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(STD(fish.length))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(SUM(fish.weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(SKEW(fish.weight))>,
 <Feature: sex_adult.PERCENTILE(MEAN(fish.length))>]>
```

However, increasing `max_depth` beyond 4 did not create more additional features. The rules DFS follows were not creating more features.  But in general, by adding more primitives, entities, and data types, there are more combinations which can lead to more of these "stacked" features.

Comment: You are correct about the structure of the raw data.  I will review later when I have some time.  Thanks!